# Calculating the total of a string, while converting to HH:MM:SS, using iiF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a string field which displays a time duration as a time and I need to

1. Convert this to `HH:MM:SS` and take into account overflow once it gets past 24 hours which I can do with this bit of code:

   ```vb
   =Floor(Sum(Fields!Duration.Value) / 3600) & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Duration.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
   ```
2. Only display results based on 2 `IIf` statements, which I do with this code:

   ```vb
   =SUM(IIF(Fields!style.Value="Incoming" AND Fields!DDIName.Value="value name",Fields!Duration.Value, 0))
   ```

Independently they work but if I try to amalgamate them, like so:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!style.Value="Incoming" AND Fields!DDIName.Value="value name",Floor(Sum(Fields!Duration.Value) / 3600) & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Duration.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss"), 0))
```

Then it all goes wrong...

Comment: Are you *really* still using SSRS 2012? SQL Server 2012 completely ran out of support at the start of last month.

Comment: yes, but not by choice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SSRS can't SUM the strings so the values would need to stay as seconds for the SUM and then converted to the mm:ss format.

```
=Floor(Sum(IIF(Fields!style.Value="Incoming" AND Fields!DDIName.Value="value name", Fields!Duration.Value, 0)) / 3600) 
& ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(IIF(Fields!style.Value="Incoming" AND Fields!DDIName.Value="value name", Fields!Duration.Value, 0)), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```